# Mahapps metro themes not available as no app.xaml

Tags: mahapps.metro, app.xaml

I am working on an *Office Add-In* and wanted to add a *WPF Mahapps Windows*.

Everything went well, but I cannot apply the *Mahapps Windows* style.
Looking  at the tutorial [here](https://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html) I see that I update the `App.xaml` to add the various themes. As it is not a WPF project, I don't have the `App.xaml`.

What is the most efficient way to apply the style?
Can I do it directly at the Windows level?
Or do I need to manually create an `App.xaml`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put all the MahApps.Metro resources also inside a Window resource tag like

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="StyledWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls">
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml"/>
        <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
  </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks!